# PyQt Subclass from QTableWidgetItem and QWidget

Tags: python, class, pyqt, pyside, qwidget

Im making a QTableWidget in Pyqt and ran into a bit of an annoying hiccup.

I need to use widgets in my table for its functionality, so im using setCellWidget to add them to the table. However, widgets dont have the same methods available as QTableWidgetItem's do (especially regarding selection in the table).

Im wondering if its possible to do something subclassing both items, so i can have the methods of both, and how i woulda dd that to the table.

Something like:

```
class TableItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem, QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableItem, self).__init__(parent)

        self.check = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Some Text')
        self.h_box = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_box.addWidget(self.check)    
        self.h_box.addWidget(self.label)
```

and then somehow add that to my table as a TableWidgetItem so it displays widgets and also has selection methods available.

Any ideas here?

For reference:
setCellWidget: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget
QWidget: (easy to find, i cant post more than 2 links)
-Which doesnt have the nice methods for a table
QTableWidgetItem: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#type
with isSelected and setSelected (Methods not avialble from a widget used in setCellWidget.

To return the widget in a cell you can use table.cellWidget(row, column) and then use your widgets methods on that. But beacuse setSelected and isSelected arent methods of a widget, you cant check for selection. I was hoping to subclass the two together to allow for both

--Basically I need to know how to get my class to 'return' the proper type when i call it to add to the table with setItem

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want the items in your QTableWidget to be widgets themselves, rather than the normal QStrings, ints, etc, that are typically used to make QTableWidgetItems?

Comment: Correct. there is a method setCellWidget in QTableWidget where you can use widgets in a table - which is fantastic and works great. Only problem is you dont get the nice methods that come with QTableWidgetItem like selection status and such. Ill update the question to links to each

Comment: I think your inheritance approach is basically correct. What exactly did not work with that approach?

Comment: Oh, I think that just `super()` is probably not going to work. Apart from that I think it may work.

Comment: I think super should work, py docs says it allows multi -item initializtion. But ive tried it both ways.
What im not sure about is how to then add it... basically, how to get a 'return value' from the class. Because if i run that, code above and then say 
test = TableItem()
<table>.setItem(row, column, test)

it wont add, i get errors (usually very non-descriptive ones. 
If i add a function to that that will return the hbox, then setItem wont work because hbox is a widget.

Im not sure on the last step of how to get the class to return as a tablewidgetitem. something like __repr__ ?

Comment: You should include the minimum code you have at the moment to demonstrate the manner in which it isn't working.

Comment: Thats essentially it - im not at my computer at the moment to rewrite and post - But if you make a Qtablewidget and then make that class in my example, try adding it to the tabel with setItem(row, column, MYCLASS)

Comment: is it `class TableItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem, QtGui.QWidget):` or `class TableItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem, QtGui.QTableWidget):` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but you could "inject" a method like:

```
class TableWidgetItem(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__init__(self)

    def doSomething(self):
        print "doing something in TableWidgetItem"

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

tableWidgetItem = TableWidgetItem()
widget = Widget()

def widgetFunction(self):
    tableWidgetItem.doSomething()

# as an instance method
settatr(widget, "widgetFunction", MethodType(widgetFunction, widget, type(widget)))

# or as a class method
settatr(widget, "widgetFunction", widgetFunction)
```

Then you can:

```
>>>widget.widgetFunction()
doing something in TableWidgetItem
```

(not tested)